# Is there any gelatin without sulphur dioxide?

Tags: food-safety, gelatin

I have bought a box of gelatin powder and saw sulfur dioxide in the ingredient list. I am just wondering about the safety of consuming them.

If there exists any gelatin without containing any sulfur dioxide? If yes, how could we differentiate between them and the ones with undeclared sulfur dioxide?

Comment: What makes you think that sulphur dioxide would be "undeclared" on an ingredients list?

Comment: I'm also confused about this question... how exactly would you have "undeclared" ingredients on an ingredient list? Unless you're buying bootleg stuff (which you shouldn't if you're concerned about food safety), all ingredients and traces will be declared on the label and will be added to safe amounts according to your local rules and regulations

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most (if not all) gelatine contains sulfur dioxide as a preservative/biocide (certainly [Dr Oetker's does](https://www.oetker.co.uk/uk-en/our-products/home-baking/baking-ingredients/gelatine/gelatine-sachets)). However most vegetarian gelatine substitutes, such as [Dr Oetker's Vege-Gel](https://www.oetker.co.uk/uk-en/our-products/home-baking/baking-ingredients/gelatine/vege-gel), do not. (Note: if using a vegetarian gelatine substitute read the instructions, as they sometimes have to be used slightly differently to animal-derived gelatine.)

The presence of sulfur dioxide should be indicated on the label, either as sulfur dioxide, sulphur dioxide, or E220 (at least in North America and the EU and other places with food labeling laws). I'm not sure if the question is because of a particular intolerance to sulfur dioxide or a general desire not to want to eat sulfur dioxide. If you have a serious allergy to sulfur dioxide or any other product you should contact the manufacturer, your doctor, or a properly accredited and registered dietitian/nutritionist, not rely on strangers on the internet for advice.

Comment: Depending on location, sulfur dioxide is declared as E220, you might want to add it to the answer :)

Comment: Sulphur dioxide is a residue of powdered gelatine manufacturing. It should be declared on the label in Europe if it's greater than 10 parts per million (traces). In USACanada or Australia there is no obligation to include traces in the labelling, but sure it does contain it.